# Command line or maven plugin for generating documentation out of wsdl

Tags: wsdl

When i was looking for document generator from WSDL, i found couple of tools like, oxygen, adivo tech writer etc; But i didn't find a command line or maven plugin which i can use to auto generate the documentation. Please suggest if you know of any such tool.

Answer (score 0):

Adivo TechWriter does support a command line interface. The syntax is documented here:

http://www.adivo.com/doc/webservice/Console.html

I've not tried it with maven, but it works fine with msbuild.